# Upload an excel file and add/update record in Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a functionality where i upload an EXCEL file and add/update those record(sheet 1) into SQL server. Now i was able to add the data in SQL server with [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/636719/Import-MS-Excel-data-to-SQL-Server-table-using-Csh).

But what it does, it truncates the table and adds the value again. I don't want to do that because there are 30% of data are generic and can not be deleted. There is field called OSID in excel sheet and same in database.That is the unique key in my table. What i want to do is update only those values in database where it matches with the key from database from the excel sheet.

Comment: What you need to do is prepare `merge` command, iterate through each excel row, and execute the merge. Merge adds row when this row doesn't exist. Use parametrized query for efficiency.

Comment: Look at the code in there. It should (but doesn't) use truncate. It deletes all the rows and then inserts every row in the spreadsheet. I agree with @T.S., use MERGE for this.

Comment: Thanks i will try to add those records into a stating table and try to merge records with join query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the code from that link to import the excel data to a separate staging table and update your main table with a join to your staging table.

From that link, the table name they used was tdatamigrationtable. Your update query would look something like

```
update m set m.col1=s.col1, m.col2=s.col2, m.col3=s.col3 
from dbo.mytable m 
  inner join dbo.tdatamigrationtable s on m.osid = s.osid;
```

Comment: Ok Grate ,i thought of that but was wondering is there any simple solution for that. I will try to implement that and will come back to you.

Comment: @arpanshah What did you end up doing with this issue?